# What HTML5 images events are available to the developer

Tags: javascript, html, image, dom-events

I have created a HTML5 Web App.

I use an image control.

When the image src is assigned I set a local variable =1
When the image has finished loading I set it to 0.

If the variable = 0 and there is another image available from my server I repeat the process.

If the img.onerror is raised i set the local variable to 0

I have noticed that if my mobile loses internet connection and then gets it back that the local variable is 'stuck' on 1 and the img.src is never updated. This does not happen all the time though.

I am guessing that neither img.onload or img.onerror has been raised. So my question is are there any other events the img control raises that I can put handler in for?

The code:

My JS function is notified by signalR that an image is available on my server.

```
if (ImageIsLoaded1.Status = 0) {
    var d = new Date();
    var n = d.getTime();
    ImageIsLoaded1.Status = 1;                   
    staticImgArray.src = './NewFrame.ashx?a=' + n
}

staticImgArray.onload = function () { ImageIsLoaded1.Status = 0; };
staticImgArray.onerror = function () { ImageIsLoaded1.Status = 0; };
```

Comment: @closer HI, I thought I had asked a good question. How shall I improve the question?  i am keen to learn. thanks

Comment: Supply a minimal amount of code that shows the problem.

Comment: :) is that any better?  I thought the verbose was enough but fair point to make

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/), here is the IDL definition of all possible [global event handlers](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#event-handlers-on-elements,-document-objects,-and-window-objects). The image element as an element should support all these handlers.

```
interface GlobalEventHandlers {
       attribute EventHandler onabort;
       attribute EventHandler onblur;
       attribute EventHandler oncancel;
       attribute EventHandler oncanplay;
       attribute EventHandler oncanplaythrough;
       attribute EventHandler onchange;
       attribute EventHandler onclick;
       attribute EventHandler oncuechange;
       attribute EventHandler ondblclick;
       attribute EventHandler ondurationchange;
       attribute EventHandler onemptied;
       attribute EventHandler onended;
       attribute OnErrorEventHandler onerror;
       attribute EventHandler onfocus;
       attribute EventHandler oninput;
       attribute EventHandler oninvalid;
       attribute EventHandler onkeydown;
       attribute EventHandler onkeypress;
       attribute EventHandler onkeyup;
       attribute EventHandler onload;
       attribute EventHandler onloadeddata;
       attribute EventHandler onloadedmetadata;
       attribute EventHandler onloadstart;
       attribute EventHandler onmousedown;
       attribute EventHandler onmouseenter;
       attribute EventHandler onmouseleave;
       attribute EventHandler onmousemove;
       attribute EventHandler onmouseout;
       attribute EventHandler onmouseover;
       attribute EventHandler onmouseup;
       attribute EventHandler onmousewheel;
       attribute EventHandler onpause;
       attribute EventHandler onplay;
       attribute EventHandler onplaying;
       attribute EventHandler onprogress;
       attribute EventHandler onratechange;
       attribute EventHandler onreset;
       attribute EventHandler onresize;
       attribute EventHandler onscroll;
       attribute EventHandler onseeked;
       attribute EventHandler onseeking;
       attribute EventHandler onselect;
       attribute EventHandler onshow;
       attribute EventHandler onstalled;
       attribute EventHandler onsubmit;
       attribute EventHandler onsuspend;
       attribute EventHandler ontimeupdate;
       attribute EventHandler ontoggle;
       attribute EventHandler onvolumechange;
       attribute EventHandler onwaiting;
};
```

Comment: OK, let me see what I can do with that - ta